# Javafx equally spanned toggle button

Tags: javafx-8, fxml, togglebutton

I need to make a group of toggle button like the following, with the white background being the selected button, and two buttons take 50% width of the parent container. Two toggle buttons are place inside HBox. The styling

[image]

So far I tried, stuck like this.

[image]

```
.viewType .toggle-button {
    -fx-padding: 0 2 0 2;
    -fx-background-color: #000;
    -fx-text-fill: white;
}

.viewType .toggle-button:selected {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-background-color: white;
    -fx-text-fill: black;
    -fx-border-wdith: 2;
    -fx-border-color: black;
    -fx-border-radius: 4;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want both buttons to have equal width, use a `GridPane` instead of a `HBox`, and use column constraints to make the two columns equal widths:

```
GridPane grid = new GridPane();
grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(createCol(), createCol());
ToggleButton toggle1 = new ToggleButton("...");
toggle1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
ToggleButton toggle2 = new ToggleButton("...");
toggle2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
grid.addRow(0, toggle1, toggle2);

// ...

private ColumnConstraints createCol() {

    ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
    col.setPercentWidth(50);
    col.setFillWidth(true);
    return col ;

}
```

You can further control how big the grid pane is in its parent by configuring the parent (details depend on what type of pane is used for the parent).

SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EqualSizedButtons extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        grid.getStyleClass().add("viewType");
        grid.getColumnConstraints().addAll(createCol(), createCol());
        ToggleButton toggle1 = new ToggleButton("A");
        toggle1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        ToggleButton toggle2 = new ToggleButton("This is really big button B");
        toggle2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        grid.addRow(0, toggle1, toggle2);

        new ToggleGroup().getToggles().addAll(toggle1, toggle2);

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        root.setBottom(grid);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);
        scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private ColumnConstraints createCol() {

        ColumnConstraints col = new ColumnConstraints();
        col.setPercentWidth(50);
        col.setFillWidth(true);
        return col ;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the buttons maxWidth to max double in java side. This will provide your buttons to same width in HBox. Hope it is useful:

```
btn1.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
btn2.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
```

You can check the following link for useful information related with sizing and aligning nodes:

[Sizing and Aligning Nodes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/size_align.htm)